# A good value sound library search engine for the Mac?

Tags: library, search, engine, mac

I'm looking into having a sound library search engine for my sounds. My organised folders and filenames work to a point, but I can see soon it will get a little too much. I've looked at some of the professional sound library search engines, like Sound Miner and NetMix but they all seem very expensive for what I need.

I'm basically after just a sound library search engine which allows for meta tags to be added to allow easier searching. Does a more good value solution exist for the Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Audiofinder. There's a new version coming out (5 and soon I hope), and feels faster and like a proper database now. Shame it doesn't support plugin chains (yet?).

Comment: I think with version 5 it does look like meta tags is supported. Excellent stuff.

Comment: Please answer this question: Quick pitch-shifting from Audio Finder to DAW? --> http://bit.ly/bX7fN0

Comment: @georgi.m Yes. it's the best

Answer (score 3):

Basehead is currently in Beta for Mac.  Final release is supposed to be very soon.  It is under $300 and every bit as good (and better in some ways) as Soundminer.

Comment: I use Basehead on Windows and is really good. I totally recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best for you is Audio Finder from Iced Audio. http://www.icedaudio.com/ It's not expansive and works well. 
Soundminer is too expansive, and crash too often for me, but it's really powerfull with the spot and metadatas editing.

Comment: I was thinking Audio Finder... But I can't seem to find the feature of adding and searching by meta tags?

Comment: metadata = version 5.

Answer (score 2):

You almost always get what you pay for. That being said, although it is slightly pricey, my vote goes to Soundminer. Not only is it an excellent search engine with comprehensive metadata and networkcapabilities, it's also a great sound design tool:

http://designingsound.org/2010/02/charles-deenen-special-quick-sound-design-with-soundminer-and-plugins/

Comment: Soundminer is a great tool, my only complaint is the proprietary metadata format.  If they ever make it so that the metadata can be read by any program, I'd be very happy.  For now, I'll be sticking with the Digibase Browser in Pro Tools.

Answer (score 0):

stamper,check it out before you shed loads of dosh, used by some of my film sound FX editors

Comment: Stamper? I can't seem to find it on the internet? Do you have a link?

Answer (score 0):

Soundminer HD, a new version that's available for as little as $199.  I've been running with the Pro version ($299) and it works wonderfully, very fast SRC.  Its like a hybrid of Soundminer v4 Standard and Miniminer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, they all come up a bit less than ideal for me. I am using AudioFinder at the moment, simply because it exists. The interface is rather convoluted, which is a side effect of the sheer amount of features in the software. It does do a whole lot, and much of it is very useful. There is another called LibraryMonkey that I'm keeping my eye on.

At the end of the day, the only way to get what you really need would be to build your own, but that's a whole other mess. I guess I'd recommend AudioFinder for a turnkey solution that is very affordable.