# Suggestions for 'sound fx library management software'

Tags: software, recording, file-organization, soundminer

I am looking to buy software to organize my sound recordings. I record, edit and mix on a Pro Tools 9 system use a Mac computer. It be great to hear from some professionals or any sound guys who use such software (like/including soundminer).

Cheers!

-Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

I've heard great things about Audiofinder for the budget conscious ( http://www.icedaudio.com/ ) from a few people, hopefully Georgi will chime in here, he's a fan. It has a spot to Pro Tools feature which I already know I'd be using day in day out if I had it, as well as the ability to edit and search metadata for your files.

Soundminer comes highly recommended too but I've never tried it so can't comment.

Comment: I've read some good things about it. Much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Soundminer would be my vote.

I've tried several different methods and this is by far the fastest and most streamlined workflow IMHO.

A similar question has already been asked, however, I encourage you to read it first:

[A good value sound library search engine for the Mac?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/122/a-good-value-sound-library-search-engine-for-the-mac)

Comment: I've also heard good things about Soundminer. It SEEMS to be the most common among professionals. I'm gonna look into it more. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I use SoundMiner v4 Pro and its easily been worth the investment....
To compare other options I surveyed metadata support in sound library apps a while ago:
http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/metadata-support-in-sound-library-apps

Answer (score 0):

I use SoundMiner V4 Pro too.

In my opinion this is the best software out there! Its very pricey but its well worth it.

If you are spending 12 hours every day searching for SFX this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the demo for Basehead on Mac - it's relatively inexpensive compared to Soundminer v4 (Pro), but I personally did not really like it. Have now started using Soundminer HD+. It's very good, and fast in both searching and adding metadata. However there's one big issue with it that I failed to notice before purchasing: it only transcodes up to 48kHz. You can still export higher res audio files by simply dragging and dropping, but the transcoding is used for a lot of its more funky project file sorting/organisation functions. In other words, that functionality becomes moot as soon as you're working with files of higher resolution than 48K. For this, you'll need to spend $200 more and get v4 (which I've never used).

All in all I would still recommend Soundminer HD+, certainly when compared to Basehead which is in its price class, for its ease of use and file search/library management.

Comment: @Jonathan, in fact, today somebody pointed out to me that HD+ has a feature that's called 'reference original file'. I didn't have much time to check this out, but from what I saw it looks like that engaging this function bypasses the transcoding altogether, meaning that you should be able to make full use of all the program's functions without having to downsample. But like I said, I've not had the time to fully confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

I think Soundminer Pro V4 is a great piece of software. Especially if you are recording lots of your own sound, the metadata options are very good.