# Tagging audio regions or segments in a sound/music database

Tags: metadata, database, tagging

Hi all,

I would like to be able to non-destructively tagg only a region of an audio file or song, and index it as an individual entry in a music database.

I have seen a number of interesting audio/music database systems for sound design and composition, including audio finder, sound miner, basehead and snapper. From these my favorites were audio finder and sound miner as they allow for customisation of tags and user-defined fields within the metadata database. (For a previous discussion on audio database software in this forum please see [here](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/122/a-good-value-sound-library-search-engine-for-the-mac) ).

However, none of these software feature any tagging function for audio regions or segments - the tagging options they offer only apply to the entire audio file.  Most songs feature various different aural components at different times, or maybe one same audio region can be interesting in different ways. Splitting the audio file and creating a new one is impractical and resource (time, hard drive space) consuming. Wouldn't it be great if an audio/music database allowed you to create individual entries that referred or linked to different parts, regions, segments or fractions of an audio file? Just like you can add time stamps to a youtube video or a soundcloud song, that you could do that to your audio files and tagg them, and index them with your criteria in a database.

I'm pretty sure some software used in the film industry does this, as it allows to timecode not only video but also audio. Some software like snapper and sound miner allows you to add timestamps or timecode data to a song, but it does not index this as a separate editable entry in the database.

The closest I have found to this is a function in Atlas.ti, which allows you to code parts of any multimedia file (audio, video, images, documents) and it functions as a layer - it only access but does not modify the original file. This is what I'm looking for, but although Atlas.ti works well for research, it does not feature any audio editing functions or audio metadata like the sound database software I've seen.

I've seen [a patent application](http://www.faqs.org/patents/app/20120197650#b) for something that apparently does exactly what I'm looking for, but I couldn't find any software that implements it, so I'm turning to you guys for orientation and advice. Maybe there is no such implementation yet, but any thoughts or orientation towards similar functions in existing software would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!
Pli